# how to bundle/build project with added functions?

Tags: javascript, github, build, bundle

I need a script for some project I'm working on, but I also need to add a function to it. I know where all the files are, the problem is I don't know how to bundle/build the script.

this is the [project](https://github.com/linways/table-to-excel) I want to add a function in.

in essence, I want to add a function in both javascript files in the src folder, and then recompile the files so that my functions will be added to the dist/tableToExcel.js file so that I can embed that script in the overall project and have something work. can you help me or even point me to a good source?

Comment: Just fork the repo, tweak it and build it...

Answer (score 1):

After you "download" or fork, run from command line `npm install` to install all dependencies. Afterwards, to build, run `npm run build`. Of course you would need [Node.JS](https://nodejs.dev/download/) and [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm) installed.

Using VS Code, you don't even need to leave the editor and it has shortcuts.

Usually instructions for installation appear in the README.md file.